# NHibernate mapping: is it possible to insert values into the database via a mapping file without using a property?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I am writing an application which works with a legacy database (brownfield). I have a couple of tables in which I insert data. These tables have some fields which need values of which I do not want the properties in my domain entities. Is there a way to insert the default value into the field without having to create a property for it my mapping file? I cannot alter the database to create a trigger, so it has to be done via the mapping file/.net application.

Hope someone can help. I hoped I could use a formula, but that doesn't work and I couldn't find any other ways to do it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EventListeners`

in the `OnPostInsert` / `OnPostUpdate` event you can get the db connection and ad-hoc execute a sql query.

Answer (score 2):

you could use a private / protected property.
That would mean introducing these fields into your domain model / mappings, but they would be limited to those, and not exposed to whoever uses your entities.
seems like a reasonable compromise to me.

Answer (score 0):

NH makes it rather easy

using xml see [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/13/using-nhibernate-for-legacy-databases/)
using FluentNHibernate see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9035144/671619)

the basic idea is to use PropertyAccessor on a non existing property which always has the constant value.